# How to implement Object.try! in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to shorten code like the following:

```
content = content.join("\n") if content.respond_to? :join
```

into this:

```
content.try!(:join, "\n")
```

Is this a good idea, and can it be implemented in terms of the existing `Object.try`?

Comment: If you want to throw an exception when it fails, how about `content.join "\n"`?...

Comment: You haven't explained what `try!` does. How are we supposed to tell you if it's a good idea or how to implement it?

Comment: @BradWerth I don't think the intent is to throw an exception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a version of `try` that modifies the object in-place, as in the difference between `x = x.reverse` and `x.reverse!`

To answer your questions...

> Is this a good idea

No, it's not, it's actually impossible.

> Can it be implemented in terms o the existing `Object.try`?

No, it can't, either with or without `Object.try`, it cannot be implemented at all. You cannot change an object's type in-place.

Using `.join` on an array produces a string. You cannot change an array in-place to become a string. This is why there is no `join!` method in the first place. Many of the methods on Array and Enumerable have versions with and without `!`. Many other methods do not have a `!` version. This is because the `!` version cannot be implemented.

In general, if you have a method like `reverse` and it's in-place equivalent `reverse!`  you can already use `try` just fine:

```
content.try(:reverse!)
```

If the `!` method doesn't already exist, such as `join` and the non-existent `join!`, it's because it cannot work, and you cannot make it work with a hypothetical `try!`.

---

Note that you can make something *like* this work with a proxy object, but this is a horrible overwrought solution to a nonexistent problem.

Just use `content = content.join("\n") if content` and be done with it.